# Findout if $\min(x,y)$ and $\max(x,y)$ are semigroup, monoid or group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

I need to find out whether $A \oplus B := \max(A,B)$ or $A \ominus B := \min(A,B)$ form a semigroup, monoid or group for $\oplus : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $\ominus : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

$(\mathbb{N},\oplus)$

Semigroup because $A \oplus (B \oplus C) = (A \oplus B) \oplus C$

Monoid because of the identity $e = 0$

$(\mathbb{N},\ominus)$

Semigroup because $A \ominus (B \ominus C) = (A \ominus B) \ominus C$

Not a monoid because if $e < a$ then $e \ominus a \neq a$

But I am not quite sure if they are a group too. I can not come up with an inverse. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\oplus$: It's not enough to show that $A\oplus A = A$. The definition of the identity is:

An identity is such an element $e$ that for all $a\in\mathbb B$, it holds that $ae=ea=a$.

This means it is not enough to find *an* element for each $a$, you must fint one element for all $a$. Your $0$ is a good candidate, can you show that $a\oplus 0 =0\oplus a= a$ for all $a\in\mathbb N$?

In the same way, you didn't yet show that $\ominus$ forms a monoid. You must find some element $e$ for which $e\ominus a = a$. If you cannot find it, you have to prove it does not exist.

Comment: Hi as 0 is the smallest number in $\mathbb{N}$ it should be the identity for $\oplus$. Works also if $a = 0$. On the other hand for $\ominus$ I am not sure if I can find one. As there is no biggest number in $\mathbb{N}$ nor do I know how I should prove that

Comment: OK, so your intuition now is that $\ominus$ does not have an identity element. For this, you must prove that there does not exist such an $e$ that $e\ominus a=a$ for all $a$. For this, take some $e$ and prove that there exists some $a$ for which $e\ominus a\neq a$.

Comment: Could an $\emptyset$ also be valid?

Comment: An empty set? The operation is not defined on sets!

Comment: if $e < a$ then $e \ominus a \neq a$

Comment: Correct. What is the conclusion you draw from this?

P.S. You also have to show if $\oplus$ produces a group or not.

Comment: The conclusion is that $\ominus$ is not a monoid and therefore also not a group. $\oplus$ is not a group because $a \oplus a^{-1} = e$ works only with $a=0$.

Comment: Then you are all done. $\oplus$ forms a monoid that is not a group, $\ominus$ forms a semigroup that is not a monoid.